# How can I move to the next iteration if a DOM element is not present in the page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'd like to test a wepage's few subpages with puppeteer. The webpage has some protection against bots. I've got the urls in an array, and I iterate through this array.

I'm stuck how I should re-write my code because I've faced several problems: because of the bot protection, the page sends a few "fake loaded" status to the browser before it actually loads the real content. So because of this, I think I have to wait for some DOM elements.

```
await page.waitForSelector('div.site__content');
```

to be sure that the content has been loaded. (await page.evaluate is not working because of the bot protection, it fires on the first "fake loaded" sign).

But here's another problem: if the page not loads correctly (for example because of connection timeout), I've got an unhandled promise rejection error and the iteration stops, the program's execution stops.

My goal would be that if there is any kind of error while loading a page, skip the current iteration and move to the next one, without program crash. But I have to keep the

```
await page.waitForSelector
```

part too. 
How can I achieve this?

```
(async function filterIds() {
  let filteredIds = ['url1', 'url2', '...', 'url200'];
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const context = await browser.createIncognitoBrowserContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();
  await tuneUserAgent(page);
  for (let id in filteredIds) {
    let errorPage = null;
    let url = filteredIds[id];
    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'load', timeout: 120000 });
    await page.waitForSelector('div.site__content'); // to be sure that the content has been loaded
    errorPage = await page.evaluate(() => {
      return document.querySelector('div.errorpage');
    });
    if (errorPage != null || errorPage === undefined) {
      continue;
    }
    await page.waitForSelector('div.dialog');
    let noGallery = await page.evaluate(() => {
      return document.querySelector('div[class="is-not-photo-uploaded-text"]');
    });
    if (noGallery != null || noGallery === undefined) {
      openOrNot = 5;
    }
    if (openOrNot < 4) {
      await openGallery(page);
    }
    let html = await page.content();
    await fs.writeFile(`./saved_items/${filteredIds[id].substring(filteredIds[id].lastIndexOf('/') + 1)}.html`, html, function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
    await page.waitFor(400);
  }
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An "unhandled promise rejection error" is thrown when a promise is rejected and not being caught. This is implicitly the case if an exception is thrown inside an async code block like in your case.

To catch the thrown exception, you can simply use a `try..catch` block inside your loop.

**Code sample**

```js
for (let id in filteredIds) {
  try {
    // your code
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Iteration for ${id} failed with error: ${err.message}`);
  }
}
```

All errors produced by your code should be caught by this code, except for the `if (err) throw err;` inside the `fs.writeFile` as this callback is called asynchronously and therefore executed outside of your `try..catch` block. But you could simply us the new [`fs.promises.writeFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fspromises_writefile_file_data_options) to even catch that error.

In case a error is thrown, the `catch (err) { ... }` part of the script will be called which logs the error message and the `id` for which the error happened. As the script does not crash anymore, the loop will continue with the next iteration.